# Programmatically center TextView text

Tags: android, textview

I beg some leniency here, I'm just starting with the Android SDK tutorials and I'm attempting something out of interest that's not in the tutorial itself, but I would hope would be easy.

I am trying to center a `TextView` item via code horizontally and vertically (I can do it in XML just fine). I've seen several examples of how to do this when the parent is a table or some other object, but I hope this would be easier for me to grasp. (p.s. Feel free to correct my terminology).

Here is the example code from the tutorial / my working model:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);
        textView.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);

        setContentView(textView);
    }
}
```

I've managed to locate the `setGravity` method, and I've tried to dabble in the `setLayoutParams` for it, but I'm not sure what the scope is for it as I can't locate what I should be importing to get the `WRAP_CONTENT` constant to resolve. From what I understood, centering and content_wrapping+gravity are two separate things. I'd like an example of how to do both in this case and maybe how/where I would have found the answer in the API documentation?

Comment: why take textview as root layout at all?

Comment: OK Let's try that again since I can't find a delete or edit button on here. 

I THINK the main container is a relative layout since it is using (i think) my activity_display_message.xml 
The source of this tutorial is a bit copy/paste-ish but it's located at: http://bit.ly/VDh9yS



 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" >
 </RelativeLayout>

Comment: see my edited answer it might helps you..:)

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
yourTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Perfect, short and sweet! Worked like charm! I also see that there is are CENTER_HORIZONTAL and CENTER_VERTICAL properties. Thank you Steve!

Comment: Please note that this only works if `android:textAlignment="gravity"` attribute is set to gravity. Otherwise textAlignment overrides.

Comment: for settting textAlignment programmatically; `yourTextView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_GRAVITY);`

Answer (score 26):

For dynamically center

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Broken down version of textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);, also a working and wonderful answer. Thank you Nirav!

Comment: Wish I could, I'm new and not enough rep to vote it up. I'm going to give Hari the check cause well, BOTH your answers are spot on and the poor fellow could use the rep more ;) that doesn't subtract from the fact that your answer was equally as helpful. (If I get the chance when my rep goes up, ill be sure to up vote both of you!)

Answer (score 8):

this will work for sure..

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(R.layout.your_layour); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

layout.addView(textView);

setcontentView(layout);
```

Comment: LinearLayout doesn't seem to have a CENTER_IN_PARENT property when inherited from android.widget.LinearLayout; Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);

text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

and

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

and

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

and

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

and

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

and

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

and

```
text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

And More Also Avaliable

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following code for applying the layout params to the TextView

```
LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(LinearLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: LinearLayout doesn't seem to have a CENTER_IN_PARENT property.

Answer (score 2):

if your text size is small, you should make the width of your text view to be "fill_parent". After that, you can set your TextView Gravity to center :

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText(message);
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to programmatically center `TextView` text in Kotlin:

```
textview.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
```

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```
  public void centerTextView(LinearLayout linearLayout) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(context.getString(R.string.no_records));
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(18.0f);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two need to go together for it to work.
Been scratching my head for a while.

```
numberView.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
 numberView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
```