# center text in TextView programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I created a TextView programmatically with a text and background drawable. I want to center the text in the TextView but the text was centered on the top.

[image]

here's my code in centering the text in the TextView:

```
protected class TileView extends TextView{
    private int tileType;
    private int col;
    private int row;

protected TileView(Context context, int row, int col, int tileType) {

    super(context);
    this.col = col;
    this.row = row;
    this.tileType = tileType;

    String result = Integer.toString(RandomNumber(1,9));            
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(tile_id[tileType]);
    setBackgroundDrawable(image);
    setClickable(true);
    setText(result);        
    setTextAppearance(context, R.style.boldText);           
    setOnClickListener(GameView.this);
}
}
```

here's my code in onLayout()

```
int left = oneFifth * tileView.getCol();
int top = oneFifth * tileView.getRow();
int right = oneFifth * tileView.getCol() + oneFifth;
int bottom = oneFifth * tileView.getRow() + oneFifth;
tileView.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
tileView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

How can I center the text in the TextView?

Answer (score 3):

Try this hope it may help you

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);   

 yourTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775743/programmatically-center-textview-text)

Comment: I already included it in onLayout function but it doesn't work.

Comment: textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);add this

Comment: changed setGravity(Gravity.CENTER) to that one but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @Mirage01 create relative layout add try the above added link

Comment: My layout was LinearLayout. You mean I'll change it to RelativeLayout?

Comment: @Mirage01 did you see the link that i have added

Comment: I tried the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams but it wont work either

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

I center my text in the .XML using                     `android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`

Comment: the TextView was created programmatically, not in XML.

Comment: ah.. sry.. then *say the same as AlexGo*

Answer (score 1):

You have to add it in the layoutparams like:

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            params.gravity=17;
```

17 is constant for CENTER in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#CENTER).

Comment: params does not have a property of weight and gravity

Comment: Try importing LinearLayout.LayoutParams , in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#gravity)