# How to set align (right or left) of text in TextView, programmatically

Tags: android, alignment

```
TextView textView=(TextView)customview.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

How to align text left?
I was looking for solution but what i found is only setting aligment in XML file..

Comment: What is the parent of textView ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically center TextView text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775743/programmatically-center-textview-text)

Comment: @SushinPv Sounds like they want to align the `TextView` within the parent, not the text within it. That's what I meant.

Comment: @MikeM. In the question it is not specified that he is looking for making the text alignment with respect to parent or not. Its sounds like he want to make the text left or right `"How to align it left? I was looking for solution but what i found is only setting aligment in XML file..
android "`

Comment: @SushinPv Yeah, still sounds to me like the `TextView` itself. We'll have to wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @AndroidBegginer weather you are looking for to make the text in the `TextView` align left or right ?? as default it will be left align

Comment: I want to align text in TextView

Comment: @AndroidBegginer as default it will be left aligned

Comment: I set up to be centered as a default, what i need is that i change it to left programmatically during the main activity @SushinPv

Comment: @SushinPv From that ^, and the comment they left on your answer, I think they want something like `setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL)`.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes it is eventually coming to that ans

Comment: @SushinPv , it only works with vertical aligment , not horizontal , i dont know why

Answer (score 4):

That looks much clear.

```
yourTextView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)
```

Answer (score 2):

Either you can add the below code in xml file and there are other alignment also present.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewResponse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:gravity="end" />
```

Or you could add below line in java file but it requires API level 17.

```
    textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_END);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            // add a rule to align to the left
            textViewLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);

            // make sure the rule was applied
            textView.setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);
```

try, this is work for me.